# On the convergence parameters of the series

Tags: sequences-and-series, prime-numbers

Denote $p$ as primes, $c$ as composites and $n$ as natural numbers. We already know that $\sum \frac{1}{p}$, $\sum \frac{1}{c}$ and $\sum \frac{1}{n}$ diverge. Let $u$, $v$ and $w$ be the convergence parameters (don't know how to define it strictly) of $p$, $c$ and $n$ respectively, and we have

$$\sum \frac{1}{p^u} \text{ converge where } u>1 \text{ and diverge where } u \leq 1,$$

$$\sum \frac{1}{c^v} \text{ converge where } v>1 \text{ and diverge where } v \leq 1,$$

$$\text{and } \sum \frac{1}{n^w} \text{ converge where } w>1 \text{ and diverge where } w \leq 1. \text{ (aka p-series)}$$

The proofs for them are easy (just the comparison test). I wonder what happen if we combine those series, so I proved that the series

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{p_k^u c_k^v}$$

converges where $u+v>1$ and diverges where $u+v \leq 1$. Here is the [proof](https://u.osu.edu/luo.525/files/2017/07/Math_Paper-1vi2bs1.pdf).

The method I used can be similarly applied to the series such as $\sum \frac{1}{pn}$, $\sum \frac{1}{cn}$ and even $\sum \frac{1}{pcn}$ (of course more cases may be discussed) and the results are also similar (converges where the sum of the convergence parameters is greater than 1 and diverges otherwise), so I have a conjecture.

We have several infinite series $\sum \frac{1}{a_1}$, $\sum \frac{1}{a_2}$ ... $\sum \frac{1}{a_n}$ and their convergence parameters are $p_1$, $p_2$ ... $p_n$ respectively. If each series converges where $p>c$ and diverges where $p \leq c$ ($c$ is a constant), for the series

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{a_{1k}^{p_1} a_{2k}^{p_2} ... a_{nk}^{p_n}},$$

can we conclude that it converges where $\sum_{i=1}^n p_i>c$ and diverges where $\sum_{i=1}^n p_i \leq c$? Can someone help me prove or disprove this conjecture? Any kind of help is appreciated.

P.S. There is a nice way to find some qualified series to test the conjecture. Denote $P_{ad}$ as a set of all primes such that $p \equiv a \bmod d$ where $a$ is coprime to $d$ (e.g. $P_{13}$, $P_{23}$, $P_{14}$, $P_{34}$ ...). The reciprocals of primes in each set can form a divergent series ([Dirichlet's theorem on arithmetic progressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions)) and their convergence parameters are all 1 (can be proved by the comparison test).